# What are the different types of memories which can come under shared memory?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

For example in a multi-threaded program, Global, volatile, extern variables, can come under critical section as they can be accessed by multiple threads at once. 
Also shmget() allocates shared memory.
I'd like to know what all other memory types can be critical sections in both user space and kernel space.

Comment: Critical sections concern sections if _code_, not data.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  It's so off the mark as to what a critical section even *is*, that it's somewhat akin to asking "what type of vegetable is a cow?".  There's no real answer to the question other than "...WTF?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout these links for a good understanding on shared memory regions and **[critical sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)** in action on real world systems.

[**bcook.cs.georgiasouthern.edu/cs523/critical.htm**](http://bcook.cs.georgiasouthern.edu/cs523/critical.htm)

[**blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/08/24/455741.aspx**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/08/24/455741.aspx)

[**ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-synchronization/index.html**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-synchronization/index.html)

Comment: Like pipes(unix) and global variables are shared memory, what all other stuff can come under shared memories?

Comment: Global variables are NOT shared memory. They are strictly limited to a process. Also technically pipes aren't shared memory either, rather piping and shared memory are two different means of Inter-Process communication(IPC).

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is generally included under critical sections. Reason being shared memory can be accessed by multiple threads at one time. To make sure certain shared memory is accessed by only one thread at one time, critical sections are used.

Not sure if shared memory is further categorized.

Comment: Like pipes(unix) and global variables are shared memory, what all other stuff can come under shared memories?

Comment: Per my knowledge, anything which gets allocated on other than Thread Stack comes under shared memory and can actually be accessed by multiple threads. Only Thread Stack memory is private to any thread, all other memory locations would come under shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory may differ when you're talking about different concepts, i.e two processes that use a common data, a queue for example, you need to "take care" of the critical sections upon modifying/adding/removing.
As for threads, everything is shared except the stack, and the code segment, so theoretically each piece of data that's reached by the main process, is a shared memory between those threads.

Comment: Like pipes(unix) and global variables are shared memory, what all other stuff can come under shared memories?